# What is a **iterable expression** in the context of Python comprehension?

Tags: python

The [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-or-test) says

> However, aside from the iterable expression in the leftmost for clause, the comprehension is executed in a separate implicitly nested scope.

Common syntax elements for comprehensions are:

```
comprehension ::=  expression comp_for
comp_for      ::=  ["async"] "for" target_list "in" or_test [comp_iter]
```

## What I've got

(please correct me if something goes wrong)

Consider this example

```
[i**2 for i in range(3)]
```

the whole line is a comprehension.

where `i**2` plays the role of expression, and `for i in range(3)` plays the role of comp_for, `i` plays the role of target_list, `range(3)` plays the role of or_test.

## Question

What is a **iterable expression**?

In this particular case, is `i**2` or `i` the iterable expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iterable expression is, presumably, `range(3)`, because it is an expression that produces an iterable object.

What the docs mean in terms of scope is that *the expression that defines the range you're iterating through* (in this case, `range(3)`) is evaluated in terms of the current local scope. Then, *everything else in the comprehension* is evaluated in its own nested scope.

This is similar to the `for` loop that you'd get from unpacking the comprehension:

```
comprehension = []
# introduce i to local scope
# note that range(3) is being evaluated in terms of the current scope 
#    (OUTSIDE the loop) instead of the nested scope (INSIDE the loop)
for i in range(3):
    comprehension.append(i**2)
# remove i from local scope, as if the scope inside the for loop was nested
del i
# i is not present in the current scope
```

```
# evaluate range(3) in terms of the outer scope
# make a nested scope, and put i in it
comprehension = [i**2 for i in range(3)]
# once the comprehension is done executing, exit that nested scope
# i is not present in the current scope
```

---

Normally in python, an entire function has its own scope, and individual blocks of code within that function (e.g. conditionals and loops) all share the same scope. But a comprehension creates an inner scope that disappears once you leave that comprehension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are the **scope** in `range(3) is being evaluated in terms of the current scope (OUTSIDE the loop)` and the **scope** in `evaluate range(3) in terms of the outer scope` the same meaning?